# Get the value of button inside a Jquery Template

Tags: jquery

Ok, i am looping through a JSON dataset and populating a div, using Jquery templates. For each loop, i create a button, with a value.

Now, i hook up the click event to a function within the loop using this:

```
<button id="btnAddGoodGuy" class="btn  btn-success btn-xs" type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Good guy?" onclick=" addGoodGuy(event); " value="${MatchedString}"><i class="fa fa-user-md"></i></button>
```

my problem, is the value of the button within the function addGoodGuy is always the first value. So in my loop if had three button with value a value b and value c respectively, i'd always end up with value a, irrespective of which button i clicked.

So far, my addGoodGuy function looks like this:

```
    function addGoodGuy(event) {
           event.preventDefault();
           $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
           var matchedItem = $('#btnAddGoodGuy').val();
           alert("The value is " + matchedItem);
     }
```

How can I get at the individual button values within my function?

Comment: You have several button with ID's "btnAddGoodGuy" right ? try with something like this : var matchedItem = $(this).val();

Comment: yes same id, different values.

Comment: Your IDs must be unique on each element.

Comment: same id, what a plonker, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't use the same `id="btnAddGoodGuy"` for different buttons. try this way:

```
<button class="btn btn-success btn-xs" type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Good guy?" onclick=" addGoodGuy(event, this); " value="${MatchedString}"><i class="fa fa-user-md"></i></button>
```

and the function

```
function addGoodGuy(event, element) {
       event.preventDefault();
       $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
       var matchedItem = element.value;
       alert("The value is " + matchedItem);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to make your `id`s to be unique (*otherwise it is invalid html*)

Then you should avoid using event attributes (*inline scripts*) and bind the handler through jQuery.

```
<button id="btnAddGoodGuy" class="btn  btn-success btn-xs" type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Good guy?" value="${MatchedString}"><i class="fa fa-user-md"></i></button>
```

And bind the handler to the container `div` (*the one you are populating*)

```
$('containerDivId').on('click', 'button.btn', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var value = this.value;
    alert("The value is " + value);
});
```

Comment: Gaby, for some reason, binding like this doesn't work when I use Jquery templates. I spent many an hour trying to get the button to even fire, let alone obtain the value

Comment: having said that, i didnt use this approach, so i'll give a bash

Comment: @CSharpNewBee you need to use the delegated version (*the one i have posted*) of `.on` where you pass it a selector for matching descendant elements. If you could post some html i could provide a more accurate solution.. This means you only bind once and it will handle the event even if you re-populate that `div` later on..

Comment: for brevity, i've dropped the raw template code in fiddler 
http://jsfiddle.net/BnN4w/

Comment: @CSharpNewBee, you are using `id`s in general in the template and that is a bad practice if the template is applied multiple times. (*you need to alter them before each insertion or remove them altogether*). The posted code should work as long as you change the `#containerDivId` i use with one that belongs to a container element of all applied templates.